# Pyramid: LookupError: Entry point 'main' not found in egg 'XXX'

Tags: pyramid

I'm trying to set up a Pyramid starter app on a mod wsgi server.  I have followed other's examples with the code below.  However I'm getting the error:

```
LookupError: Entry point 'main' not found in egg 'Pyramid_starter'
```

Any advice on what I am doing wrong?

I have ran the below setup with now errors:

```
python setup.py develop
```

**application.py (entry point for the mod wsgi server)**

```
import os
import sys

from pyramid.paster import get_app
from pyramid.paster import get_appsettings

here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
project_folder = os.path.basename(here).lower()
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(here, project_folder))
config = os.path.join(here, 'development.ini')
```

!!! Both of these lines of code generate the error

```
application = get_app(config, 'main')
settings = get_appsettings(config, 'main')
```

My development.ini file:

```
###
# app configuration
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/narr/environment.html
###



[app:main]
pyramid.includes = pyramid_chameleon
use = egg:Pyramid_starter

pyramid.reload_templates = true
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = en


# By default, the toolbar only appears for clients from IP addresses
# '127.0.0.1' and '::1'.
# debugtoolbar.hosts = 127.0.0.1 ::1

###
# wsgi server configuration
###

[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 6543

###
# logging configuration
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/narr/logging.html
###

[loggers]
keys = root, pyramid_starter

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = INFO
handlers = console

[logger_pyramid_starter]
level = DEBUG
handlers =
qualname = pyramid_starter

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your .ini file. Change the following

```
[app:main]
pyramid.includes = pyramid_chameleon
use = egg:Pyramid_starter
```

to

```
[app:main]
use = egg:Pyramid_starter
pyramid.includes = pyramid_chameleon
```

The use = egg:Pyramid_starter comes first

Comment: If this help, mark it as answer so it will be usefull to others

Comment: Thanks. I setup the Pyramid project using Pycharm 4.0.1.  It installed Pyramid 1.52.  That install placed the 'pyramid.includes' directive there and another where it should be below the 'use' and other 'pyramid.' directives.  I just removed the wrong one not knowing.  Having both generated a different error.  I guess its a bug in Pyramid 1.52 or how Pycharm uses it to install.  I never had this problem with Pyramid 1.4

Comment: BTW. The install also puts a double "config.include('pyramid_chameleon') in Main in __init__.py